# npm express install is adding extra dependancies

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

When I cd into my project and npm install express --save it not only injects express into my node_modules but also installs a lot of other dependencies that I do not need or want. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall node and npm. I am using homebrew to install node. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

> npm install express --save

```
 ─┬ express@4.13.4 
  ├─┬ accepts@1.2.13 
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.9 
  │ │ └── mime-db@1.21.0 
  │ └── negotiator@0.5.3 
  ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
  ├── content-disposition@0.5.1 
  ├── content-type@1.0.1 
  ├── cookie@0.1.5 
  ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
  ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
  │ └── ms@0.7.1 
  ├── depd@1.1.0 
  ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
  ├── etag@1.7.0 
  ├─┬ finalhandler@0.4.1 
  │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
  ├── fresh@0.3.0 
  ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
  ├── methods@1.1.2 
  ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
  │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
  ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
  ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
  ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.10 
  │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
  │ └── ipaddr.js@1.0.5 
  ├── qs@4.0.0 
  ├── range-parser@1.0.3 
  ├─┬ send@0.13.1 
  │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
  │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.3.1 
  │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1 
  │ ├── mime@1.3.4 
  │ └── statuses@1.2.1 
  ├── serve-static@1.10.2 
  ├─┬ type-is@1.6.11 
  │ └── media-typer@0.3.0 
  ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
  └── vary@1.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely running npm version 3 or above. This version made it so all dependencies of dependencies are stored in the root node_modules folder.

See here for more info: https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just changed my dev computer and reinstalled everything so I do have the newest version now. I could not figure out why this was occurring and it was driving me mad! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, the module you're trying to install must have his own dependencies to work properly, so they are installed at the same time in your node_modules